# Why is my report not showing data in devExpress XtraReport?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm creating a report in VS2013 C# winform application using devExpress XtraReport.  I'm trying to use a table in the entity framework as the datasource.  I tried this using a binding source, but the data does not show.

From my dataProvider class:

```
public static List<vwInventoryRequestReport> GetView(int docNo) 
{ 
    var items = new List<vwInventoryRequestReport>(); 
    using (var context = new Sage300Entities()) 
    { 
        var query = from i in context.vwInventoryRequestReports 
                    where i.InventoryRequestHeaderId == docNo 
                    select i; 
        items = query.ToList(); 
    } 

    return items; 
}
```

From my main class:

```
var docNo = Convert.ToInt32(teDocumentNumber.Text); 
var items = DataProvider.GetView(docNo); 
this.bindingSource2.DataSource = items; 
InventoryRequestReport report = new InventoryRequestReport(); 
report.DataSource = items; 
ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
```

Comment: Please provide some code and describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: From my dataProvider class


   public static List<vwInventoryRequestReport> GetView(int docNo)
        {
            var items = new List<vwInventoryRequestReport>();
            using (var context = new Sage300Entities())
            {
             
                var query = from i in context.vwInventoryRequestReports
                            where i.InventoryRequestHeaderId == docNo
                            select i;
                items = query.ToList();
            }
            return items;
        }

Comment: from the main                var docNo = Convert.ToInt32(teDocumentNumber.Text);
            var items = DataProvider.GetView(docNo);


            this.bindingSource2.DataSource = items;
         InventoryRequestReport report = new   InventoryRequestReport();
            report.DataSource = items;
            ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);